# Gitlab runner not able to execute helm list command

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, helm3

I'm trying to setup a gitlab kubernetes agent and runner for my in-cluster CICD pipeline.
My gitlab.ci is something on the line of:

```
stages:
  - deploy

deploy-new-images:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: alpine/helm:3.7.1
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - helm list --all-namespaces
  tags:
    - staging
    - test
```

Gitlab is able to start the container for this particular job but fails with the following error:

```
Error: list: failed to list: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

My agent deployment has a service account named `gitlab`. This service account is associated to the default admin ClusterRole via a ClusterRoleBinding; it is also associated with a Role via a RoleBinding resource.
The role has the following definition :

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-04-14T15:27:27Z"
  labels:
    app: gitlab-agent
  name: gitlab-agent
  namespace: gitlab
  resourceVersion: "44732"
  uid: 0b09cabe-826f-4c7c-a864-3192e0c9ea42
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

The gitlab runner on the other hand was deployed via Helm using the following values:

```
  image: "gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v14.9.0"
  imagePullPolicy: "Always"
  replicas: 5
  gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.com
  runnerRegistrationToken: "{{ vault_gitlab_runner_registration_token }}"
  unregisterRunners: true
  logLevel: "debug"
  rbac:
    create: true
    rules:
    - resources: ["*"]
      verbs: ["*"]
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["*"]
      verbs: ["*"]
  clusterWideAccess: true
  metrics:
    enabled: false
  runners:
    executor: kubernetes
    locked: false
    tags: "staging,test"
    name: "test-staging-gitlab-runner"
    runUntagged: false
    config: |
      [[runners]]
        [runners.kubernetes]
          namespace = "gitlab"
          image = "ubuntu:20.04"
```

It seems to me that both the agent and the runner have sufficient permissions and yet the helm list command is failing. Any idea?

Comment: please share the output of `kubectl auth  can-i get pod --as system:serviceaccount:gitlab:default`

Comment: @P.... Oh, nice one. I dint know about auth. It outputs no, so i guess it doesnt have permission to "get" the pod resources?Well thanks for pointing in the right direction. I guess now i know it's about that!:)

Comment: yes, you can now fix the permissions. do `kubectl auth  can-i --help` for more options and details

Comment: @P.... Wierd though, I though setting RBAC during charts installation would suffice. Ill update tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:** In your gitlab-runner values file, add the setting `service_account = "gitlab"` under `[runners.kubernetes]`.

**Explanation:** The actual pod that executes the job is not the gitlab-runner pod, nor the gitlab agent pod. Gitlab runner kubernetes executor spawns a new pod for each job. The place to set the service account name for these pods is in the above setting.

The error message above shows that the pod running the job was using the default service account for the `gitlab` namespace. this service account doesn't (and shouldn't) have the required permissions.

The section `runners.config` in the values file, ends up in the config.toml file that configures the runner. Here is the documentation about config.toml for kubernetes executor: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#other-configtoml-settings

And here is the [Kubernetes executor interaction diagram](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html#kubernetes-executor-interaction-diagram)

Comment: Thanks, I understood that a dedicated pod was goin to be instantiated for each job, although I thought the serviceaccount would be shared with that of the runner. Again, thanks for your time. Have a great one!